# Where does the US Electoral College physically meet?

Tags: united-states, electoral-college

From what I understand, electors gather in special meetings at the Statehouses of each relevant State.  Is this correct?  What is the actual physical process for the College being convened and voting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> From what I understand, electors gather in special meetings at the Statehouses of each relevant State. Is this correct? What is the actual physical process for the College being convened and voting?

By law, the legislature of each state determines where the actual meeting takes place and the process for voting.<sup>1</sup> [A summary list of state laws is available from NASS.](https://www.nass.org/sites/default/files/surveys/2017-08/research-state-laws-pres-electors-nov16.pdf)

After the voting is completed, six certificates, of all votes given, are prepared.<sup>2</sup> The governor is responsible for sending the certificates to the Archivist of the United States.<sup>3</sup>

---

<sup>1</sup> [3 U.S. Code § 7.](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/3/7) Meeting and vote of electors

> The electors of President and Vice President of each State shall meet and give their votes on the first Monday after the second Wednesday in December next following their appointment at such place in each State as the legislature of such State shall direct.

<sup>2</sup> [3 U.S. Code § 9.](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/3/9) Certificates of votes for President and Vice President

> The electors shall make and sign six certificates of all the votes given by them, each of which certificates shall contain two distinct lists, one of the votes for President and the other of the votes for Vice President, and shall annex to each of the certificates one of the lists of the electors which shall have been furnished to them by direction of the executive of the State.

<sup>3</sup> [3 U.S. Code § 6.](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/3/6) Credentials of electors; transmission to Archivist of the United States and to Congress; public inspection

> It shall be the duty of the executive of each State, as soon as practicable after the conclusion of the appointment of the electors in such State by the final ascertainment, under and in pursuance of the laws of such State providing for such ascertainment, to communicate by registered mail under the seal of the State to the Archivist of the United States a certificate of such ascertainment of the electors appointed, setting forth the names of such electors and the canvass or other ascertainment under the laws of such State of the number of votes given or cast for each person for whose appointment any and all votes have been given or cast; and it shall also thereupon be the duty of the executive of each State to deliver to the electors of such State, on or before the day on which they are required by section 7 of this title to meet, six duplicate-originals of the same certificate under the seal of the State; and if there shall have been any final determination in a State in the manner provided for by law of a controversy or contest concerning the appointment of all or any of the electors of such State, it shall be the duty of the executive of such State, as soon as practicable after such determination, to communicate under the seal of the State to the Archivist of the United States a certificate of such determination in form and manner as the same shall have been made; and the certificate or certificates so received by the Archivist of the United States shall be preserved by him for one year and shall be a part of the public records of his office and shall be open to public inspection; and the Archivist of the United States at the first meeting of Congress thereafter shall transmit to the two Houses of Congress copies in full of each and every such certificate so received at the National Archives and Records Administration.

Answer (score 3):

The Electoral college does *not* meet in one place. However it meets separately in state capitols. This is because of travel distances in the early days of the US.